# how to run c ++ code in Intel HD Graphics 4000?

Tags: c++, opencl, gpu, intel

I recently needed to accelerate a convolution operation in C ++ and I wondered if it is possible in some way, without using OpenGL or OpenCL, to use some functions of the Intel HD Graphics 4000 to speed up some operations such as convolution or matrix multiplication.

Comment: Have you already tried some of the SIMD [intrinsic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_function) available on your CPU first? And without OpenCL or similar how would you even get access to the computing power of the GPU?

Comment: Sure it's *possible*, just write your own drivers for the hardware so you can talk to it without OpenCL.  Or were you looking for some higher-level interface that's more convenient than OpenCL instead of less?  I don't think there are any compilers that auto-detect loops that could run on a GPU and do it all for you, but maybe such tools exist...

Comment: The convolution or the matrix multiplication are not part of the optimized set of operations in the compilers. Generally it is done through libraries using parallelization, for example, EIGEN3 + OPENMP, however what I want is a primitive function that I can use from the graphic card.

Comment: I think you should ask yourself why you don't want to use OpenCL/GL. But Intel Compiler has special functions for offloading to GPU. [https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/how-to-offload-computation-to-intelr-graphics-technology ] but I have not tried it.

Comment: On Windows and Visual C++ you could use "AMP" (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh265137.aspx). AMP makes use of whatever supported accelerator it finds and is relativly simple to implement (much easier than OpenCL or CUDA in my Opinion)

Comment: I am currently working on deep learning algorithms. I know the intel compiler, but I have always had the tendency to use open source tools, such as GCC. I'm really looking for something that I can create myself and that works in linux operating system.

Comment: Afaik there is a Microsoft/AMD compiler called "HCC" for linux too: https://github.com/RadeonOpenCompute/hcc/wiki. It supports 4 different computing modes - one of them is AMP - but also a mode called "HC" (Hererogenos Computing). Heard of it some time ago but never tried it myself. But maybe it misses the main point: Seems to be working only on AMD gpus :(

Comment: *what I want is a primitive function that I can use from the graphic card*:  Intel's Linux GPU drivers are fully open-source (https://01.org/linuxgraphics), and there are manuals for the hardware.  Feel free to look into the details to see how OpenCL code will compile to Intel GPU instructions on Linux.  As I understand it, compiling an OpenCL compute kernel for a specific GPU is very similar to compiling C/C++ source to machine code for a specific CPU.  I think it's *possible* to write code directly in GPU machine language / asm for a specific GPU, but it won't be portable between models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:** to my best knowledge, there is no **non-hacky**, documented, compiler-independent, standard C++ way here.

Intel provides a convolution example using Intel Compiler specific extensions here:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/610441

However, **the Cilk Plus stuff became deprecated with the 18.0 compiler**.

The 
[Release Notes](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-c-compiler-180-for-linux-release-notes-for-intel-parallel-studio-xe-2018)
state offload support for *Intel® Graphics Technology*.
The required command line flag is `-qopenmp-offload=gfx`.

So the most portable non-OpenCL way would be using OpenMP Offload directives. They **might** get implemented for the Intel Graphics architecture by other compilers as well at some point. Also, the code would still be portable and default to self-offloading for architectures not supported by the used compiler.